Jenkins can't find GitHub repo
Here's the following error I get once I start a job:
Started by user admin
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Your account is suspended. Please login to reactivate your account.
fatal: unable to access '[MY REPO]': The requested URL returned error: 403

    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2846)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2185)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:635)
    at PluginClassLoader for git//jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:408)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at PluginClassLoader for git//jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:413)
    at PluginClassLoader for scm-api//jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:219)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:126)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:73)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-job//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:311)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:446)
Finished: FAILURE

I tried multiple procedures, including fetching (the command which failed the build, in the errog log) from my machine via the shell or via GitHub Desktop, which works fine. I checked the credentials I entered in Jenkins and regenerated the PAT, but still nothing.
The build works fine on other people's Jenkins, not me.

stderr: remote: Your account is suspended. Please login to reactivate your account.
Please reactivate your account & try again.

That's not it. My account is not suspended. I can connect to GHE without a problem. There's not even an option to reactivate an account if it is already activated.

You can contact GitHub Support.

Started by user admin, I am guessing that is not the account you are connecting to Github as and presumably not the one you are trying your procedures as. Seems like an identity/account issue.
